# How to locally build an ionic app taken from a .git repository

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I was trying to build [Moodle's ionic mobile app locally](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2) on [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/windows) by following the below steps:

```
cd project-directory

ionic platform add android
```

The command prompt returns the below error:

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Adding android project...
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\zameer\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-andr
oid\4.1.1\package\bin\create.bat D:\ionic\moodlemobile2-master\moodlemobile2-mas
ter\platforms\android com.moodle.moodlemobile "Moodle Mobile" --cli""
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.moodle.moodlemobile
        Name: Moodle Mobile
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-22
Copying template files...
Android project created with cordova-android@4.1.1
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\ionic\moodlemobile2-maste
r\moodlemobile2-master\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\ionic\mo
odlemobile2-master\moodlemobile2-master
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\ionic\moodlemobile2-maste
r\moodlemobile2-master\hooks\after_prepare\020_add_ios_transport_security.js D:\
ionic\moodlemobile2-master\moodlemobile2-master
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'plist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object. (D:\ionic\moodlemobile2-master\moodlemobile2-master\ho
oks\after_prepare\020_add_ios_transport_security.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
Error: Hook failed with error code 1: D:\ionic\moodlemobile2-master\moodlemobile
2-master\hooks\after_prepare\020_add_ios_transport_security.js
```

Everything *seems* normal till the below part of the above error block:

```
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'plist'
```

My aim is to run this project locally to see [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) in action

> What is this `plist` module? Why is it not getting detected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After cloning a Git repository that contains a Ionic app, you need to run these 2 additional commands:

#### Install Node.js dependencies

```
npm install
```

It will install all the **Node.js** dependencies in the local `node_modules` folder. The modules considered are the ones listed under `dependencies` and `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file located at the root of the cloned Git repository.

#### Install Cordova plugins

```
ionic state restore
```

This command looks at the `cordovaPlugins` and `cordovaPlatforms` attributes in the `package.json` file and install the additional platforms and plugins code required for the app.

Comment: `npm install` or `npm install -g ionic`? Because this command on the [official website](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) is not matching

Comment: If you already installed Ionic with -g (globally) you should not need to reinstall it. 'npm install' is to install the app **dependencies**

Comment: In my case, I had to also create an empty ./www folder in the root of the repo to avoid this error.

Comment: This solution is really good. I even reinstalled npm because of dependency issues. never knew that I have to do this for cloned git repos

Comment: I have executed "ionic cordova prepare" command on iOS because of message "ionic state" has been removed

Answer (score 2):

You did not execute npm install so you are missing the required packages.

Read [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) on what need to be done to work with ionic.

Go into the project folder where the `package.json` is in and execute the `npm install` form that folder.

Comment: ionic is already installed. Do we need to re-install ionic for every new project?

Comment: ionic is installed globally on the machine but the packages should be in all your projects. so you will need to install dependencies per project.  checkout to see if you have the nde_modules folder

Comment: @arainone Let me start again. I'll get back after trying this. Thanks to both of you!